# WebBrowser control scripts not running

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm developing in C# .NET (4.5) a winform which contains a WebBroswer control.

This WebControl navigates to a webpage which contains the following line:

```
<a title="Cancel" class="button deny" onclick="postCancel();" href="javascript:void(0)"> Cancel  </a>
```

The script is not executing, although it works fine when I just navigate to this page using IE (that is, without using the WebBroswer control hosting it).

I searched for a solution and the only thing that I found (which indeed solves the issue)

is to add my application to  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key in the registry  (HKLM > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Internet Explorer > Main > FeatureControl > FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION).

I just wonder if this is indeed the only way to handle this issue? is there any way to solve this programmatically without changing the registry?

Note: I have no control on the web page itself...

Comment: Not submitting as an answer because I'm not 100% sure, but it's the only way that I've found...  I spent a lot of time looking into this one.

Comment: Does the script throw any kind of error, or does it really not run at all? Make sure your WebBrowser control is not set to suppress errors. Otherwise I'd concur and say browser emulation is the only solution I know of. I know it's not overly helpful, but the .NET WebBrowser is ancient and awful. There are plenty of great alternatives like CefSharp :-)